# What is the difference between parameters in parentheses vs. inside the 'params' block?

Tags: powershell, parameters, syntax

In powershell you can declare parmeters like:

`function My-Function($someParemeter) { Do something... }`

But can also use:

`function My-Function { param($someParameter) DoSomething... }`

What is the difference? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: There is none that I'm aware of expect for using a `param` block is a lot cleaner

Comment: You can specify [`Cmdletbinding()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2) attribute only when using `param`. Note that you can still create an advanced function cmdlet even without `param`, by using `[Parameter()]` attribute in front of parameter name.

Comment: @zett42 I think thats worth an answer, totally forgot cmdletbinding was not possible using the first syntax clearly never use it :P

Comment: @Santiago, we already have a post that covers this - please see the linked duplicate. Daniel, I hope that duplicate answers your question.

Comment: Amazing answer and my question is definitely a duplicated. Thanks guys :)